# Perl or Python script to remove user from group

Tags: python, perl, system-administration, centos, redhat

I am putting together a Samba-based server as a Primary Domain Controller, and ran into a cute little problem that should have been solved many times over.  But a number of searches did not yield a result.  I need to be able to remove an existing user from an existing group with a command line script.  It appears that the usermod easily allows me to add a user to a supplementary group with this command:

```
usermod -a -G supgroup1,supgroup2 username
```

Without the "-a" option, if the user is currently a member of a group which is not listed, the user will be removed from the group.  Does anyone have a perl (or Python) script that allows the specification of a user and group for removal?  Am I missing an obvious existing command, or well-known solution forthis?  Thanks in advance!

Thanks to J.J. for the pointer to the Unix::Group module, which is part of Unix-ConfigFile.  It looks like the command deluser would do what I want, but was not in any of my existing repositories.  I went ahead and wrote the perl script using the Unix:Group Module.  Here is the script for your sysadmining pleasure.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Usage:   removegroup.pl login group
# Purpose: Removes a user from a group while retaining current primary and
#          supplementary groups.
# Notes:   There is a Debian specific utility that can do this called deluser,
#          but I did not want any cross-distribution dependencies
#
# Date:   25 September 2008

# Validate Arguments (correct number, format etc.)
if ( ($#ARGV < 1) || (2 < $#ARGV) ) {
  print "\nUsage: removegroup.pl login group\n\n";
  print "EXIT VALUES\n";
  print "     The removeuser.pl script exits with the following values:\n\n";
  print "     0 success\n\n";
  print "     1 Invalid number of arguments\n\n";
  print "     2 Login or Group name supplied greater than 16 characters\n\n";
  print "     3 Login and/or Group name contains invalid characters\n\n";
  exit 1;
}

# Check for well formed group and login names
if ((16 < length($ARGV[0])) ||(16 < length($ARGV[1])))
{
  print "Usage: removegroup.pl login group\n";
  print "ERROR: Login and Group names must be less than 16 Characters\n";
  exit 2;
}

if ( ( $ARGV[0] !~ m{^[a-z_]+[a-z0-9_-]*$}) || ( $ARGV[0] !~ m{^[a-z_]+[a-z0-9_-]*$} ) )
{
  print "Usage: removegroup.pl login group\n";
  print "ERROR: Login and/or Group name contains invalid characters\n";
  exit 3;
}

# Set some variables for readability
$login=$ARGV[0];
$group=$ARGV[1];

# Requires the GroupFile interface from perl-Unix-Configfile
use Unix::GroupFile;

$grp = new Unix::GroupFile "/etc/group";
$grp->remove_user("$group", "$login");
$grp->commit();
undef $grp;
exit 0;
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use Perl::Critic on this program.

Comment: Is that a general comment, or is there something obvious and silly that I wrote into the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Link:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-roadmap4/

To add members to the group, use the gpasswd command with the -a switch and the user id you wish to add:

gpasswd -a userid mygroup

Remove users from a group with the same command, but a -d switch rather than -a:

gpasswd -d userid mygroup

"man gpasswd" for more info...

I looked for ages to find this.  Sometimes it takes too much effort not to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Dave,

Amazing - who'd thunk that the command would look like a password utility ...

Thanks!
Loren

Answer (score 2):

I found [This](http://search.cpan.org/~ssnodgra/Unix-ConfigFile-0.06/GroupFile.pm) for you. It should do what you need. As far as I can tell Perl does not have any built in functions for removing users from a group. It has several for seeing the group id of a user or process.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *deluser --group [groupname]* should do it.

If not, the *groups* command lists the groups that a user belongs to.  It should be fairly straightforward to come up with some Perl to capture that list into an array (or *map* it into a hash), delete the unwanted group(s), and feed that back to *usermod*.

Comment: On the Centos 5 installation I am working with, there does not appear to be a "deluser" installed on the system.  I am currently looking for it in the repositories.  I have started working on a perl script, but it will probably take me an hour or two to get the perl side of my brain spooled back up.

Comment: Apparently deluser is Debian specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple little Perl script that should give you the list of groups you need:

```
my $user = 'user';
my $groupNoMore = 'somegroup';
my $groups = join ',', grep { $_ ne $groupNoMore } split /\s/, `groups $user`;
```

Getting and sanitizing the required arguments is left as an execrcise for the reader.